# trouble locating Bahamas DEM

Tags: dem

I'm having a hard time finding a DEM for the Bahamas. North Bimini specifically. Does anyone have advice? Or a DEM?

Comment: You could try SRTM elevation data https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/SRTM1Arc

Comment: For open data the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange is the place that I would research/ask this.